# Cannot reassign kafka topic partition

Tags: apache-kafka

The version of kafka is kafka_2.12-2.2.0, zookeeper is 3.5.4-beta.

1.start broker 0

```
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon config/server.properties
```

2.create a topic named test

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 192.168.18.128:2181/kafka --topic test --create --partitions 2 --replication-factor 1
```

describe of topic test is

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 192.168.18.128:2181/kafka --topic test --describe
Topic:test  PartitionCount:2    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: test Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

3.now I start broker 1,and I want to move partition-1 of topic test to broker 1.Then I create a json file named reassign.json, content of reassign.json is

```
{
    "version": 1, 
    "partitions": [
        {
            "topic": "test", 
            "partition": 1, 
            "replicas": [
                1
            ], 
            "log_dirs": [
                "any"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I exec command to move partition-1

```
./bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper 192.168.18.128:2181/kafka --reassignment-json-file json/reassign.json --execute
```

4.After a few seconds,I exec comand to show result of previous command.

```
./bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper 192.168.18.128:2181/kafka --verify --reassignment-json-file json/reassign.json
Status of partition reassignment: 
Reassignment of partition test-1 is still in progress
```

I retry 2 times,bug the reassignment of partion is still in progress.

5.Then I get following error log in server.log.

```
[2019-09-13 15:37:04,696] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Error when handling request: clientId=0, correlationId=6, api=UPDATE_METADATA, body={controller_id=0,controller_epoch=1,broker_epoch=62,topic_states=[{topic=test,partition_states=[{partition=1,controller_epoch=1,leader=0,leader_epoch=0,isr=[0],zk_version=0,replicas=[1,0],offline_replicas=[]}]}],live_brokers=[{id=0,end_points=[{port=9092,host=ubuntu,listener_name=PLAINTEXT,security_protocol_type=0}],rack=null},{id=1,end_points=[{port=9092,host=ubuntu,listener_name=PLAINTEXT,security_protocol_type=0}],rack=null}]} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Epoch 62 larger than current broker epoch 28
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.isBrokerEpochStale(KafkaApis.scala:2414)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleUpdateMetadataRequest(KafkaApis.scala:236)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:114)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:69)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Had anyone resolved the same issue? Would you mind sharing your options? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your configs and all worked good for me. From the error at number 5 i can see that the replicas of your `partition-1` are `[1,0]` while you have a replication factor of 1.

Based here (check replicas):

```
[2019-09-13 15:37:04,696] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Error when handling request: clientId=0, correlationId=6, api=UPDATE_METADATA, body={controller_id=0,controller_epoch=1,broker_epoch=62,topic_states=[{topic=test,partition_states=[{partition=1,controller_epoch=1,leader=0,leader_epoch=0,isr=[0],zk_version=0,replicas=[1,0],offline_replicas=[]}]}],live_brokers=[{id=0,end_points=[{port=9092,host=ubuntu,listener_name=PLAINTEXT,security_protocol_type=0}],rack=null},{id=1,end_points=[{port=9092,host=ubuntu,listener_name=PLAINTEXT,security_protocol_type=0}],rack=null}]} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

Check if you have added an extra step somewhere that adds `broker-1` as a replica for `partition-1`.

Comment: ErgiNushi,thanks for your reply. The reason is I made a mistake.I have two vms, both hostname is ubuntu.And in server.properties of kafka, the value of property listeners is default, ```#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092```.As a result, broker-0 and broker-1 has the same endpoints.```"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://ubuntu:9092"]```.I modify hostname of node0 as node0,node1 as node1,and set ```listeners=PLAINTEXT://node0IP:9092``` of broker-0, set ```listeners=PLAINTEXT://node1IP:9092``` of broker-1.Then,It worked.